# print second column value after exact match of variables in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

I have a file list.txt containing data like this

```
hvar-mp-log.hvams europe@gmail.com
mvar-mp-log.mvams japan@gmail.com
mst-mp-log.mst  korea@gmail.com
pif-mp-log-pif atlas@gmail.com
```

I need to match the string in the  list.txt and print the matched string second column data.

if string=mst-mp-log.mst print korea@gmail.com.
I can match string like this example

```
   grep -q "$string" list.txt
```

how to print matched string mail id. expected output should be like korea@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
string="mst-mp-log.mst"
awk -v var="$string" '$1 == var {print $2}' list.txt
```

Or, if your grep command is already returning the correct lines, perhaps:

```
grep -q "$string" list.txt | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: The option "quiet" (-q) is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using individual commands in a pipe:

```
$ grep '^mst-mp-log.mst ' list.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
korea@gmail.com
```